# How to modify line number 3 (n) and every n+6 (like 9, 15, 24 and so on) in VSCode with my custom string?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have gathered a very big data in a `.txt` file containing around 6K lines, and I want to modify line 3 at first which is called now `n` and every `n+6`th line, like 9, 15, 24 and so on.

This is an example of the current state:

```
domain_name = {'name': 'aaa.pro'
'register': 159.00
'register': 159.00
'register': 159.00
'currency': USD

domain_name = {'name': 'abogado'
'register': 40.50
'register': 40.50
'register': 40.50
'currency': USD

domain_name = {'name': 'academy'
'register': 34.50
'register': 34.50
'register': 34.50
'currency': USD
```

I want the result be something like:

```
domain_name = {'name': 'aaa.pro'
'register': 159.00
'renew': 159.00
'register': 159.00
'currency': USD

domain_name = {'name': 'abogado'
'register': 40.50
'renew': 40.50
'register': 40.50
'currency': USD

domain_name = {'name': 'academy'
'register': 34.50
'renew': 34.50
'register': 34.50
'currency': USD
```

So that the line number 3 which is `n`, and then line numbers 9, 15 and so on (n+6) that contain `register` string should be replaced by `renew` string.
Would you please how may I reach it?

Comment: What language are you coding on?

Comment: I want to finally manipulate this file into dictionary in Python but the file is just a `.txt` file with strings.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were looking to solve a coding problem. After your edit I see what you meant

Comment: I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the word `domain_name`
2. Use: **Select** | **Select All Occurrences**
3. <kbd>ArrowLeft</kbd> <kbd>ArrowDown</kbd> <kbd>ArrowDown</kbd>

Now you have a cursor on each line you want to edit.

Exit Multi Cursor with <kbd>Esc</kbd>

If you have a very big number of lines to select you might need to do it in parts after splitting the file in parts. VSC only handles max 10000 Multi Cursors.

---

**Edit**

In the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-line-number) (v0.13.0) there is a command (`selectby.lineNr`) to place cursors on lines where the line number matches a boolean expression.

1. Place the cursor on the first line you want to have a cursor (in this case line 3)
2. Start command: **Place cursor based on line number, uses boolean expression**
3. Enter expression: `c+6k`

Read the document to see what other expressions you could use to select multiple lines.

Comment: @Saeed I have made an edit for another method using an extension